# How to resolve libwkhtmltox.so reference in .Net AWS Lambda Docker image

Tags: docker, .net-core, aws-lambda

I'm converting a .Net 2.1 lambda to 3.1 (or higher) and struggling with resolving the references that convert html to pdf. I'm currently using code from this solution https://github.com/HakanL/WkHtmlToPdf-DotNet, which works fine running a console app in the container. The lambda package is introducing issues that break this logic. Using a new lambda solution with this WkHtmlToPdf-DotNet project, the deployed image fails with this exception

GetModule WkHtmlModuleLinux64 Exception System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library '/var/task/runtimes/linux-x64/native/libwkhtmltox.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I am using the LD_DEBUG environment variable which shows before the exception: file=runtimes/linux-x86/native/libwkhtmltox [0];  dynamically loaded by /var/lang/bin/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.12/libcoreclr.so [0]

And I also output to the log a search for the file which yields this line:
GetFilePath res: /var/task/runtimes/linux-x64/native/libwkhtmltox.so

Any suggestions how to continue to troubleshoot this?

Thanks,
Reuven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by installing few of the packages that is required by DinkToPdf library in a docker container environment.

The issue however for installing those packages were not straight forward in Amazon Linux 2 instances. Below is the docker file I had to add for the DinkToPdf work properly.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:core3.1

WORKDIR /var/task

COPY "bin/Release/lambda-publish"  .    
RUN yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

RUN yum install -y libgdiplus \
        ca-certificates \
        fontconfig \
        freetype \
        libX11 \
        libXext \
        libXrender \
```

For this to run I also had to copy the three dependent library files after build libwkhtmltox.dll, libwkhtmltox.dylib libwkhtmltox.dll.so.

Comment: Is there a solution for this when using the managed runtime?

Comment: @NinovanderMark, Could you please elaborate?